# option:selected not working inside $.map()

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I've started writing a function to replace select boxes with a custom HTML list. I can't seem to get the ":selected" Selector to be recognize for selected options though. I've tried a few methods and my select box does have options with selected attributes ;]

Any help with this is very appreciated.

```
$('select').each(function(){
    var $ulSelect = $('<ul />');
    var $options;
    var $numSelected = 0;

    $options = $('option', this).map(function(index, element){
        var $selectedClass = '';
        if ($(element).is(':selected')) {
            $numSelected++;
            $selectedClass = ' class="selected"';
        }
        return $('<li data-value="'+ $(element).val() +'"'+ $selectedClass +'>'+ $(element).text() +'<a href="#" class="x-link"></a></li>');
    }).appendTo($ulSelect);

    var $ulSelectWrap = $('<div />')
        .addClass('ul-select-wrap')
        .prepend($ulSelect)
        .prepend('<span class="selected">'+ $('option:eq(0)', this).text() + $activeText +'</span>');

    $(this).hide().before($ulSelectWrap);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code in jsFiddle, and found no problems with selecting an element that was, well, actually selected. The problem I've encountered is that you cannot `.appendTo` an array (which is returned by .map()). So I suggest using this instead:

```
$.each($options, function() {
    $(this).appendTo($ulSelect);
});
```

And another problem is, I suppose, is using `$('option:eq(0)', this)` instead of `$('option:selected', this)`; the former always shows the first option as active (though only `li` element corresponding to selected element correctly has the `selected` class).

Check [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5eq48/) to see the updated version of your code.

Comment: I should say that I'm trying to identify which options are selected on page load. I'll add a .change() listener to add the .selected class to any clicked LI elements after I've resolved this.

For now, it's still a mistery why jQuery doesn't see these options as being :selected. I've had no trouble with :selected in the past :\

Thanks

Comment: Well, still can't get what's wrong; perhaps it'd be better if you show some more code (with JSfiddle or something like that). I've changed `.change` to `.each` in my code, tried using `multiple` as well - all works pretty ok.

Comment: How strange... I just added it to JSfiddle to show an example and it works on there :/
http://jsfiddle.net/7X4tG

thanks anyway. I'll figure it out from here!